# Convert [Int] to (Int) and vice-versa in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

---

How can I convert an int array

```
let beforeSorting = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

to

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Also in reverse in swift?

### Scenario

```
var a: Int = 0
var b: Int = 0
var c: Int = 0

..likewise 20 variables
```

I wanted to apply some operations to these values, so I converted the values into array like

```
let array = [a, b, c,..] // counting 20 elements
```

After applying some operations like sorting. I need to put these values back to the properties.

So I made an tuple with these properties. Here is my problem. how can I assign my new array to tuple. (Setting all properties at once)

just like `(a, b, c, d..) = myarray`

Comment: Why would you want to convert an `Array` to a `Tuple` and vice-versa? Even if it would make sense, there's no easy way to do it, since you cannot dynamically create a tuple of a specific size unlike with an array.

Comment: I wanted to assign some property values from array as in my edit

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What is your exact goal?

Comment: @Saranjith that code in your edit makes no sense without more context. Why are the variables stored in a tuple and how do you create that tuple? Why don't you add the variables to an array straight away instead of adding them to a tuple?

Comment: hope its clear now @DávidPásztor

Comment: Int is value type so no way you can set your values into array and get values from array after array's rearrange. Consider wrapping every value in separate struct

Answer (score 1):

Tuples must have a predefined size and type. So all you can do is have some convenience which may be done on many ways. You could for instance create a wrapper:

```
typealias MyTuple = (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int)
class ToupleWrapper {
    private var values: [Int]
    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int) {
        values = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
    }
    convenience init(array: [Int]) {
        self.init(a: array[0], b: array[1], c: array[2], d: array[3], e: array[4], f: array[5])
    }
    convenience init(tuple: MyTuple) {
        self.init(a: tuple.a, b: tuple.b, c: tuple.c, d: tuple.d, e: tuple.e, f: tuple.f)
    }
    var array: [Int] {
        return values
    }
    var tuple: MyTuple {
        return (values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
func foo() {
    let arrayFromValue = ToupleWrapper(a: 3, b: 2, c: 1, d: 4, e: 2, f: 2).array
    let arrayFromTouple = ToupleWrapper(tuple: (0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2)).array
    let tupleFromArray = ToupleWrapper(array: [2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2]).tuple
}
```

Comment: nice answer. thank you. is there any simple way to achieve this. when 20 properties coming this becomes messy

Comment: @Saranjith not with tuples. Maybe if you added all situations on how you use this with examples we might be able to find a better solution.

Comment: Just a note that the initializer will crash if the array has less than 10 elements

Comment: @Cristik Yes, I was actually thinking about some defaults there but another method would be needed that would make the answer unreadable... Or each property done like b: array.count > 1 ? array[1] : 0

Comment: The right answer IMO would be either a precondition (if calling it with the wrong size array is considered a programmer error) or a failable initializer (probably `init?`). Defaults almost certainly break the point of this conversion and make it very difficult to make this generic (which is currently pretty easy).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this in a safe manner. A tuple has a fixed length that is known at compile time, while the length on an array is something obtained at runtime.

Converting a tuple into an array is possible, but only if all tuple elements are of the same type or have a common type - you can simply reference the .0 ... .10 elements of it.